# Interfacing 32 bit data to spartan3E kit by using RS 232 interface

Tags: fpga

I have 2000 data of 32 bit length. I want to interface these data from system to the spartarn 3E kit.I think using RS 232 I can interface the data to spartarn 3E kit.

If any one  have any idea how to interface the data from pc to spartarn 3E kit ,please answer.
And also say what are the steps I should follow to interface the data to spartarn 3E kit.

Advance thanks to the people who try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UART peripheral in the FPGA - either write one or download one.

Take the data from that peripheral and send it to the rest of your code in the FPGA.

You can use a terminal program to send the data from the PC to the serial port and it will (assuming all is setup correctly) appear one character after another on the inside of your FPGA on the signals connected to the UART that you created.